# Overriding method containing implicit keyword arguments with one that consumes explicit

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have following set of classes:

```py
class Parent:
    def foo(self, positional, **kwargs):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self, positional, *, first_kwarg, second_kwarg):
        pass
```

Is there any reason my PyCharm IDE tells that those signatures doesn't match? For me it's kind of awkward because you still have you signature containing kwargs but unwrapped which makes your implementation more precise for a child class and generic for a parent.

Or is there at least any common Python pattern that would allow me to build similar structures?

Comment: In the Parent there is no */*args for the remaining positional arguments after the `positional` argument. That's why they don't match.

Comment: It's because they don't match. The `Child` class has a reduced the possible number of arguments. If you look at this from a polymorphic point of view the `Child` is essentially changing the interface of the `Parent` class.

Comment: @Tim is there any common pattern in Python how to do it. One of the ways I see here is to rename `Child.foo` into `Child._foo` and wrap it in new method `Child.foo` that conforms to `Parent.foo` interface.

Comment: @PetrShypila The best advice would be to re-write your method signature as `def foo(self, positional, *, first_kwarg, second_kwarg, **kwargs)`, that will still conform to the interface of the base class. Also, keep in mind there is nothing wrong with doing this if it solves a particular problem in your application. PyCharm can't always identify every scenario perfectly in dynamic languages.